# How do I resolve the mapping values not allowed error parsing YAML in ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have the following:

```
  BrowserBlasterBasic:
    name: 'Browser Blaster Basic Account'
    app_id: 1900
    sub_target: 'zone'
    price: '0.99'
    visible: 'true'
```

I get the following error:

```
mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 12 column 7
```

Comment: Are you sure this is copied directly from the source because what you have is valid `YAML` but generally this error occurs with lines without a colon or lines where a space is omitted between the colon and the value. YAML is very sensitive to spacing so extra spaces of even tabs instead of spaces can cause consequences. It is more difficult to help since you haven't posted the complete yaml but the error is clearly on line 12 but we only have 6 lines

Comment: There aren't even 12 lines in the YAML sample you gave us, so I'm doubting that's your real input that leads to YAML complaining about something on line 12. There's nothing in the input you showed us that would lead to that error, it's in something you haven't showed us.

Comment: okay, I snipped the YAML down the list...there is comments up at the top.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear on when to use a `-`, whether there has to be a value after the `:` and so forth.  but if the above is correct, let me revisit the error.

Comment: You must have sniped more than the comments. Please re-run the program without the comments in the file and update the YAML to show everything up to the line with the error and youi'll need to update the line number in the error as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting `---` at the beggining and `...` at the end of the YAML file. Make sure to indent them correctly (starting at column 0).
I'm not an expert or anything and I don't know what causes this problem, but I had the same one and that fixed it.

Comment: You don't need a directive end marker (`---`) if you don't have any directives and as long as your document doesn't start with `%`. You need a document end marker `...` only when you need to explicitly indicate the stream is complete (or if another document follows). The production rules of YAML allow a bare document to start with whitespace. None of your recommendations provide anything useful. But it is interesting you have the same problem as the OP, i.e. an error in line 12 when parsing a **six line** YAML document. You should file a a report, because that is certainly a bug in the parser.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part with the missmatching lines. I thought the OP was just looking for an explanation for this error, like I was. The cause for this error in my case was that I didn't indent the start and end markers correctly, so I suggested this might be the cause for others reading this too.

Comment: They are both end-markers, the `---` indicateding end of directives. They are only recognised as such if they are at the start of a line **and** followed by white-space (space, newline etc).